# Displaying a single users quiz responses in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing a simple ruby on rails quiz app.  There are quizzes, questions, and question_responses.  Currently, when viewing a users response to a quiz I use something like (note that this is not the actual code, but an attempt to make the question simpler):

```
@question_responses = user.question_responses.where(quiz_id: 1);
```

Then I display the question responses in a table.

Now, I want the ability for a user to answer a question multiple times.  I have that functionality working, but in the view, I want to display only one response per question (either the correct response, or the latest response).  The above code would give me all the responses, even if the user has responded to a question multiple times.  How can I achieve this and is it possible without custom SQL?

Simplified models below:

```
quiz
  title :string

question
  title :string
  answer :string

question_response
  user_id :integer
  question_id :integer
  answer :string
  correct :boolean
```